# ExtJS 4 loading columns which meets a certain condition

Tags: javascript, extjs

So I have a store that loads data for calendar events and a view model.The problem is that I have an admin panel and user interface and I want users to see only events that are upcoming, but keep older events in the database. So I have this right now:

```
columns: [{
        header: 'Date of event',
        width: 125,
        dataIndex: 'event_time',
        renderer: this._renderExactDate,
        field: {
            type: 'textfield'
        }
        }
```

and I have this function

```
_renderExactDate: function(date) {
        var currentDate = new Date()
        var value = date;
        value = Ext.Date.parse(value,"Y-m-d H:i:s");

        if (currentDate < value) {
            return //something;
        }
        else {
            return //something;
        }

    }
```

which successfully check if the date is older than the current date but when the check is done I don't know how to prevent the whole column to be rendered in order to present a grid with only upcoming events

thanks

Leron

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just filter the store which attached to your grid to show only event that are in the future. Don't need to change `renderer()` function. Or I didn't understand your question?

Update: 
After you load the store do the following:

```
store.filter(
    Ext.create('Ext.util.Filter', {filterFn: function(r) { 
       var currentDate = new Date();
       return r.get("date") > currentDate; 
    }})
]);
```

Comment: Yeah I need only future events, but being a newbie the only idea I get was to use render. Not very sure how to filter using the store though, I'll try, but any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Check out documentation for the `filter()` method: http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-filter

Comment: Yeah, gone this far already, thanks. But still it's hard to understand how to implement what I need using only the documentation

Comment: Thanks, trying this at the moment i wonder if this one is suitable for ExtJS 4 -Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup, or this is from ExtJS 3 old syntaxis.

Comment: This is from ExtJs4 docs. You might want to add trace inside the filtering function to make sure date comparison works properly. I haven't tried it.